# Android List Item Delete Action

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in my android application . This List View is filled with Messages. Now i want to give the user a ability to select multiple messages and then delete them or move them. Clicking on the List Item displays the message details. Now i want some suggestions . 1) How can i give the user the ability to select multiple messages? check box or some other method? I use the messagesListView.setOnItemClickListener(this); to get the message that was clicked on  ? My Custom Adapter, i have overridden the setOnLongClickListener to get the long click on a List Item . But somehow this acts really strange . Like when i want to long click the short click listener is fired ? Am i making sense ? My question is how can i give the user an efficient way to select multiple items in a ListView ?

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825645/android-listview-with-multiple-select-and-custom-adapter

Answer (score 0):

**`CheckBox`** is the best way to achieve multiple selection for listview. Also you don't have to implement `onItemClick()` for this purpose. Even almost every android application give the same functionality with `CheckBox`.

Tutorial [Custom ListView with ability to check items](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/)

Comment: Please this is unexpected from you that you haven't given this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825645/android-listview-with-multiple-select-and-custom-adapter

Answer (score 0):

the android platform has definition for CheckedTextView.. try that if u want

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what version you are developing for, so it's kind of hard to give the best advice.

If you are developing for API 11+, you should use the contextual action mode with batch operation support.  See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) for more info.

Comment: I am supporting minimum android 2.1.