# Android: ListView Multiple Selection

Tags: android, listview

Problem:

When i click on the 2nd checkbox item in the listview then automatically 10th item is checked. I can not understand what's happen?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {
private int resId;
Context context;
private ArrayList<MyItem> itemList;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<MyItem> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.resId = textViewResourceId;
    this.itemList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
    this.itemList.addAll(objects);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public boolean needInflate;
    public TextView txtItemName;
    public CheckBox chkItem;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    MyItem cell = (MyItem) getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtItemName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
        holder.chkItem = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkItem);
        holder.chkItem
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        //Log.i("Pos", "" + position);
                        //cell.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    }
                });
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtItemName.setText(cell.getName());
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

"MyItem" is my pojo Class.

OnCreate Code:

```
 lvItemName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItemName);
    List<MyItem> myItemsList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        MyItem item = new MyItem(items[i], false);
        myItemsList.add(item);
    }

    ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem,
            myItemsList);
    lvItemName.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvItemName.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

"items" is my String Array.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/android-get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview-when-i-click-a-button/18164177#18164177. check this if it helps

Comment: Perhaps this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview

Comment: I have problem with checkbox means when i checked 2nd checkbox item then automatically 10th item is checked. Can you please tell me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: @lawrance:you are not setting tag  on checkeditem postion. I have suggested a link in my answer which fixes your issue.

Comment: yes you are right @user2439755. I solved my issue by adding "holder.chkItem.setTag(position);" Thanks.

Comment: @Lawrence check out this answer, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20171191/919216

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can avoid this problem by

adding a boolean array like

```
boolean[] checkboxState=new boolean['your array size here']; //global decleration
holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    checkboxState[position] = true;


                } else
                    checkboxState[position] = false;
```

This works for me and i hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

set tag on checkeditem postion.

Check out [here](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) complete working example.

Answer (score 0):

In your listview getView method, make holder.**checkbox** to **seTag(position)**.

Then use that **position** using **getTag()** method, you will get selected position there and your problem will solved. Read about **setTag(value)** and **getTag()** method.