# Change background of multiple selected item in android custom listview

Tags: android

I have a custom listview in my app in which I want to implement deleting of multiple elements in using actionmode . A person can select multiple items by activating action mode using long press on an item like happens in watsapp. I am able to select multiple items but the problem which I am facing is while changing the background of selected list item. I tried activate and selected mode but they are changing background of random elements in my list item. Scrolling over list changing the background of random items and they are changing on each scroll. Weird thing i observed.

I tried changing background both programatically or using xml but same thing is happening in both the cases.

The code of my drawable file which i had applied to top element of my list view items view

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
 <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent">   </item>
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
 <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/holored"></item>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_item_shadow"></item>
</selector>
```

Long Click Listener in List View

```
detailsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int  position, long id) {

            view.setActivated(true);
            onListItemSelect(position, view);
            return true;
        }
    });



private void onListItemSelect(int position,View view) {

    trasactionDetailAdapter.toggleSelection(position,view);

}
```

I am using SparseBooleanArray to check the item selection, mSelectedItemsIds is my object of
SparseBooleanArray.

Inside my adapter :

```
public void toggleSelection(int position,View view) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position), view);
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value,View view) {

    changeBackgroundColor(view,value);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void changeBackgroundColor(View view,boolean hasSelectedItem){
    if(hasSelectedItem){

        int color=context.getResources().getColor(R.color.holoblue);
        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }else{
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_item_backgroundstate);
    }

}
```

But even I am long pressing one item in list this code is changing the background color of multiple random items in listview, Am I paassing the wrong view to change the background ?

Comment: check out this answer, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20171191/919216

Answer (score 0):

The view that you are receiving in `onItemLongClick` is being reused for different items in your list.  This is a method the adapter uses as a performance optimization that prevents the need of creating a new view for every item in the list.  That being said you wouldn't want to perform that operation on the view that you receive there.  Instead you would want to retrieve the item by the position or id that is passed into the method.  Here is an example.

```
MyItem item = (MyItem) detailsListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
item..setActive(true);
```

In your adapter you can have it check for `item.isActive()` and draw the view differently based on that.

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {
  private final MyItem[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, MyItem[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   MyItem item = values[position];
   if(item.isActive()) {
    //Do your drawing here
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no such method exist with name `getListAdapter()` in listview. I am using subclass of `SherlockActivity` for displaying the listview.

Comment: In that case you can just use detailsListView.getAdapter().  I'll update my answer.

Comment: The above code is giving me the item associated with the row not the view so I cant call setActivated method on an Item it is a function of view.

Comment: I was implying that you can create the method on the item.  You can name the method anything you'd like.  This solution also alows you to keep the drawing of the view in the adapter.  Check the value in the adapter and draw the view accordingly.

Comment: I am not anything you said, If you can please provide some sample code. Because I tried all possible ways to do the same.

Comment: I have tried you method and it changes background of all the elements in the listview.

Comment: i have already tried this long back //Do your drawing here what should be here is my question because writing this `if(isSelected){
            int color=context.getResources().getColor(R.color.holoblue);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }` changes the background of random items. And also while scrolling he background trasfers from one item to another randomly. That is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use getter setters class for this.Put your condition in getter setter on click of item and then notify adapter and set backgrounds  of convertView according to requirement.

Comment: How it will get which view background has to be changed in Adapter ?

Comment: Changing background the background of all list elements in the listview and ya no doubt it will be.