# What is the best way to implement single choice radio buttons on an android listview that uses a custom array adapter?

Tags: java, android

I've created a custom arrayadapter to handle a json response that I'm successfully throwing into a listview. However, I'm unsure of the best way to display radio buttons next to each item... I've read about using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice as the default view, but I'm using a custom adapter and a custom xml to display my data... so I'm wondering in this case what is the best way to implement radio buttons on a listview? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652109/multiple-choice-list-with-custom-view) can help you.

Just change the line

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

to

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it's a great start and I think it will be a lot of help towards me resolving the issue. Thanks

Comment: Do you have to keep track of states yourself?