# (On Hold) android listview item of CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE custom cursorapater not highlighting

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a multi select item listview based on a custom row layout inside a fragment. I would like each checked row to be highlighted.

Problem is when i click a row the checked rows do not stay highlighted but the font color of the text changes. I do not get this issue when using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 . Thanks in advance

onCreateView Code

```
 ...
 listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
 getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER, null, this); 
        adapter = new ContactFragmentAdapter(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),null,0);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Custom row layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/simple_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="test"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your ListView xml

Comment: Hi Marcus, I have edited the question

Comment: You  should check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview

Comment: tried that, unfortunately did not work

Comment: Can u try to put  android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" in the LinearLayout of your custom row?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have a minimum api of level 8, this requires api level 11. I will investigate further and edit the question as i think maybe the issue is that the custom cursor adapter new view method keeps redrawing the item hence i keep losing the background color change

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple choice list with custom view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652109/multiple-choice-list-with-custom-view)